# Informix - error -387 when executing a procedure on remote DB

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, informix

I have a problem when executing a procedure on remote database with DBA user (informix). The error which I receive is **-387 No connect permission**. I write down very simple procedure just to show you the problem. The procedure does **insert into select from a view on a remote DB**. When I execute the SQL from the procedure in command line or in DB client I don't have any problems, when I run the procedure the error is thrown.

Here is an example to be more clear:

**Database1:**

```
create table delme (aa int);
insert into delme values (1);

create view delme_view as select * from delme;
```

**Database2:**

```
create table bbb (aa int);

CREATE procedure delme_test()
begin

insert into bbb
select *
from Database1:delme_view;
end
end Procedure;
```

When I execute procedure delme_test() on Database2, the error **-387** is return, when I execute the SQL only through DB Client (connected to Database2)

```
insert into bbb
select *
from Database1:delme_view;
```

The insert completes successfully.

Do you have any idea what could be the problem and how can I fix it?

The version of Informix is: **IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC4W1**
Both databases are on the same server and have DBA user informix.

Comment: you example works fine with dbacces. could you give us more information about the client used and informix connect librairie version. thanks

Comment: The client is IBM® Data Studio Version 4.1.0.1. I have the same problem with dbaccess. Do you use the same version of Informix?

Comment: no i have 12.10FC6. the 2 dbs have buffered logging mode. may be adding trace in your spl could help. SET DEBUG FILE TO '/tmp/delme_test.log';
TRACE ON

Comment: -387 No connect permission - this is the error